# FFmpeg not working (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

Code:

```
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
link = "https://youtube.com/watch?v=videoidhere"
voice = await bot.join_voice_channel(channel)
player = voice.create_ytdl_player(link)
player.start()
```

I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'start'
```

Might FFmpeg be broken? If yes, I can't find a way to uninstall FFmpeg deleting the installation folder.

Answer (score 0):

[`create_ytdl_player`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.create_ytdl_player) is a coroutine. So you should be awaiting the function.

```
player = await voice.create_ytdl_player(link)
```